# Android/Retrofit: "Object is not abstract and doesn't implement member"

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2

I'm trying to create a POST request to login a user with email and password parameters inside a JSON.

I'm getting the following error:

[image]

AuthService.kt

```
interface AuthService {

    @POST("/user/signin")
    fun login(@Body request: JSONObject) : Call<PostLoginResponse>

}
```

PostLoginResponse.kt

```
data class PostLoginResponse(
    val access_token: String,
    val expires_in: Number,
    val token_type: String
)
```

LoginActivity.kt

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.login)

        email = findViewById(R.id.input_email)
        password = findViewById(R.id.input_password)

        signinButton = findViewById(R.id.btn_login)
        signinButton.setOnClickListener {
            val authJsonData = JSONObject()
            authJsonData.put("email", email.text.toString().trim())
            authJsonData.put("password", password.text.toString().trim())
            login(authJsonData);
        }

    }

private fun login(jsonData: JSONObject) {

        val call = App.authService.login(jsonData)
        call.enqueue(object : Callback<PostLoginResponse> {

            override fun onResponse(call: Call<PostLoginResponse>, response: Response<PostLoginResponse>) {
                Log.i(TAG, "login() - onResponse() Result = ${response?.body()}")
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<GetSitesResponse>, t: Throwable) {
                Log.e(TAG, "login() - onFailure() ", t)
            }

        })

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Change the `call` argument type from `Call<GetSitesResponse>` to `Call<PostLoginResponse>` in the `onFailure` method:

```
override fun onFailure(call: Call<PostLoginResponse>, t: Throwable) {
    Log.e(TAG, "login() - onFailure() ", t)
}
```

Comment: Woo god.. Thanks !